# Где найти библиотеку FileUtils

Tags: java, test-automation, appium

Всем привет.

Пишу автоматизированный тест. Вот алгоритм, который должен выполнить тест:
Открыть приложение.
Нажать на список городов.
Сделать скриншот экрана устройства.
Для создания скриншотов ранее использовался класс "FileUtils", но в данный момент не могу вспомнить, к какой библиотеке он относится.

Я реализовал следующий метод для создания скриншота:

```
static void screenshot(String filePath) {
    File srcFile = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    File targetFile = new File(filePath + filename + ".jpg");
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, targetFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Однако на последнюю строчку IDE выдает ошибку:

> FileUtils cannot be resolved

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Скачать можно отсюда](https://commons.apache.org/)
 нужна версия 2.6

Comment: Это ответ? Т.е. проблема решена?

Comment: Проблема решена